# Is it possible to trigger an event when someone else makes an edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

So for example, when user **A** and user **B** are both editing a sheet and user **A** edits cell B1, I want to send a dialog to user **B**.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible. Let's think if there are Users A – Z, how would it know who to send the dialog to, and even then, you can only send a default dialog to the currently active user. However, in order to achieve your goal, you could

1. Notify User B via Email. For this you need a database or array which maps User B --> Email of User B
2. Give each User a color. When User A edits a cell, use onEdit(cell) and a map of User --> Color

Those are off the top of my head for now.